# Android Views Are Not As Tall As Specified

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I am using RelativeLayout to position views at precise locations on the screen.  This works as expected when using a view that say, draws a rectangle.  But when using Android views like EditText, they are drawn shorter than specified by about 8 units.  Clicking outside of the drawn EditText (but within the parameters specified by RelativeLayout) will, in fact, hit the EditText.

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
package com.DrawDemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class DrawDemo extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout l = new RelativeLayout(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        lp.leftMargin = 50;
        lp.topMargin = 50;

        DemoView demoview = new DemoView(this);
        l.addView(demoview, lp);

        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        l.addView(editText, lp);

        setContentView(l);
    }

    private class DemoView extends View
    {
        public DemoView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        }
    }
}
```

If you execute this, you will notice that the EditText is noticeably shorter than the rectangle.  I've tried mucking with onMeasure, setMinimumXXX, and just about everything else I can think of.  So far, the only thing that works with some level of success is to just add 8 or so pixels to the height (8 seems to work better than trying a percentage of the height).

Next task will be to step into the source but was wondering if somebody has already solved this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot? I have trouble to see in the code what you actually try to accomplish...

Comment: You can try http://img508.imageshack.us/i/screenht.jpg/.  Basically, I am adding two views with the exact same parameters.  The one view (the rectangle which I've made green for clarity) adheres to the parameters.  The other view (the EditText) is shorter than the parameters state.  The interesting thing is that I can tap the green part that shows under the EditText, and the EditText responds as if I tapped it.  So maybe I just need to fiddle with margins or something?

Comment: sorry but the screenshot is extreme blurry, I can identify what I am seeing...

Comment: It is an EditText on top of a Green Rectangle.  Because I used the exact same LayoutParams structure to place both Views, I had expected the EditText to exactly cover the Green Rectangle.  But it doesn't.  You can see the Green Rectangle behind the EditText.  However, if you click/tap the Green Rectangle, the EditText gets the event.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because of the actual EditText background image that's used. Buttons are the same way, for some reason Google decided to draw the 9-patch background images with some extra transparent padding pixels. Really, the only solution, if it's a problem, would be to draw your own 9-patch, or modify the existing Android 9-patch to remove the extra pixels.

Comment: If I call setBackgroundDrawable(null), I get the same behaviour.  In this case, you can't see the background, but the cursor, when centered, is still slightly (about 8 units) above center.

Comment: Have you tried doing `setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` or some other color, and see if the same issue still exhibits?

Comment: If you put a blue background on the EditText, it completely covers the green view underneath.  The problem is that when Android draws the interactive EditText parts, it doesn't center the interactive bits in the View area; it shifts them upward slightly.

Comment: By "interactive bits", what exactly are you referring to? If you're talking about the different state-selector images, those would have to be changed as well. I would actually expect the text (if that's what you're referring to) to be positioned slightly *below* center due to the strange font padding in the standard fonts, so that's strange if that's the case.

Comment: By interactive bits, I mean the moving parts, like the cursor for the text engine in an EditText, the committed field value, etc.